# CanCan Can? Statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following code in my ability.rb class.

```
can :update, Schedule, Schedule.where(:camp => user.camp)
```

This should allow the user to update a schedule where the schedule's camp matches the user's camp, correct (given that camp is an attribute of both camp and user)? Or am I approaching this wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I always do

```
can :update, Schedule do |schedule|
  schedule.camp == user.camp
end
```

Note that this assumes you're calling `can?` on an instance of `Schedule`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way

```
can :update, Schedule do |schedules|
  schedules.camp.id == user.camp.id
end
```